# Von vs. Durch bei Nominalisierung

Tags: difference, preposition, nominalization

Ich erinnere mich noch daran, dass bei den Vorlesungen von B2, als wir die Nominalisierung gelernt haben, haben wir folgendes Beispiel studiert:
"Durch den Kauf der Firma durch Carlos konnten die Schulden bezahlt werden"

Ich weiß dass wenn es statt "durch Carlos" "von Carlos" benutzt würde, würde das eigentlich heißen dass die Firma ihm am Anfang gehörte... Trotzdem ist es mir nicht so ganz klar, wann durch oder wann von bei Nominalisierung benutzt werden soll.

Vielen Dank Ihr Lieben :)

Comment: Ich verstehe die Frage noch nicht ganz. Mit der Nominalisierung hat die Benutzung von "durch" oder "von" nichts zu tun. Es geht um den Kontext wie du auch richtig beschrieben hast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"von" kann u.a.

1. Einen Ersatz für den Genitiv darstellen, deshalb Besitz anzeigen
2. In der Bedeutung "Urheber von etwas" verwendet werden

diese beiden Interpretationen sind "bei der Firma von Carlos" möglich und daher mehrdeutig und es wird nicht klar, ob Carlos die Firma ge- oder verkauft hat. Wenn aus dem Kontext nicht klar wird, was gemeint ist, sollte "von" nicht verwendet werden. Falsch ist die Verwendung deswegen nicht.

Klarstellen läßt sich dein Beispiel z.B. durch

1. Verwendung des Genitivs "durch den Kauf von Carlos' Firma" oder "durch Carlos' Kauf der Firma" (zweites Beispiel eher unschön, auch würde man das Markieren des Genitivs durch einen Apostroph gerne vermeiden)
2. Ersetzen von "von" durch "durch" wie gezeigt - das doppelte "durch" im Satz ist aber eher unschön.
3. Die beste Alternative scheint zu sein, die Nominalisierung komplett zu lassen und stattdessen mit "weil Carlos die Firma ge-/verkauft hat,..." vollkommen klarzustellen, was eigentlich passiert ist.